# Can you tell me why $A$ induces a surjective homomorphism from $AK^n /A^2K^n$ to $A^2K^n/A^3K^n$.why not one-one homomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra

let $A$  be an $ n \times n$ matrix  over a  field  $K$.Prove that

$\text{rank} A^2-\text{rank }A^3 \le \text{rank} A-\text{rank} A^2$

**My attempt** : [Here](https://yutsumura.com/inequality-regarding-ranks-of-matrices/) is the solution I found

It is written that

> Proof $2:-$

> Consider  the  quotient vector space $AK^n /A^2K^n$
> and  $A^2K^n/A^3K^n$

> Then the matrix mulitplication by $A$  induces  a  surjective  homomorphism  from $AK^n /A^2K^n$
> to   $A^2K^n/A^3K^n$

> Therefore  $\dim AK^n /A^2K^n
> \ge   \dim A^2K^n/A^3K^n$

**My confusion** :Can you tell me why $A$  induces  a  surjective  homomorphism  from $AK^n /A^2K^n$
to   $A^2K^n/A^3K^n$.why not one-one homomorphism ?

**My thinking** :

I know  that $A$  can  induces a linear transformation  of  $AK^n /A^2K^n$
to   $A^2K^n/A^3K^n$

If the linear transformation is one one and onto  then transformation is bijective

$\implies AK^n /A^2K^n
\cong  A^2K^n/A^3K^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V'$ be a subspace of a vector space $V$, and $W'$ be a subspace of a vector space $W$. Consider a linear map $g \colon V \to W$.
If $g(V') \subseteq W'$, then $g$ *induces* a linear map $\tilde g \colon V/V' \to W/W'$ such that
$$
\forall v \in V \quad \tilde g(v+V') = g(v)+W'.
$$
(Exercise: Prove that $\tilde g$ is well-defined.)

Observe that if $g$ is surjective, then so is $\tilde g$:
Given $w \in W$, choose $v \in V$ such that $w=g(v)$, and then note that $w+W' = \tilde g(v+V')$.

For your specific example, consider the "matrix multiplication by $A$" from $AK^n$ to $A^2K^n$, that is, the map $g \colon AK^n \to A^2K^n$ defined by
$$
\forall y \in AK^n \quad g(y)=Ay.
$$
Then, as $g$ is a surjective linear map such that $g(A^2K^n) \subseteq A^3K^n$, we have that $g$ induces a surjective linear map $\tilde g \colon AK^n/A^2K^n \to A^2K^n/A^3K^n$.

Answer (score 2):

It is not injective because it can happen that $Av\notin A^2K^n$ but $A^2v\in A^3K^n$. Consider e.g. $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}$ and $v=\pmatrix{0\\ 1}$.